# what is a good approach for handling concurrency issues in asp.net development?

Tags: asp.net, concurrency

I was wondering if I'm supposed to stick to sqldatasources and objectdatasources to fill asp.net webcontrols and if programatically binding controls is a bad practice because you have to manually control concurrency. My main concern is if there is a good approach  to control concurrency without the use of the sqldatasource and object datasources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different approaches and otyu need to pick the one that best suits your needs.

A common approach is to amend you stored procedures to check for old values.  see this article: https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-1050108.html

You can use DataRowVersion of your DataROw object to look at original, current and proposed values.

I hope this helps